# how to get Groupmembership of ADUser in csv

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

i build this script to get the groups of all users in my csv.(my imported csv file has only the sAMs of the User)

```
    $ImportPath =  Import-CSV "c:\temp\users.csv" -Encoding:UTF8
    $ImportPath | %{
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.sAMAccountName | Select-Object sAMAccountName
    } | Export-csv 'c:\temp\groupmembership.csv' -NoType
```

now the export-csv is full of groups but i don't know whicht groups belongs to which user.

Comment: But you have only selected `sAMAccountName` to be exported to csv. Are you sure you are also getting group names? Or is that the `sAMAccountName` of the AD group?

Comment: Yeah it is the SAM of the groups. But now i don't know which group belongs to which user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done it this way:

```
    $ImportPath | % {
    $groups = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.sAMAccountName | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty name) -join ','
    get-aduser $_.sAMAccountName -properties memberof,samaccountname | 
    select samaccountname, @{name="Groups";expression={$Groups}} 
    }| export-csv $ouputPath -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

ouput csv look like this

```
  A           B
User1      group1, group2,group3
user2      group2,group3, anotherGroup
```

So cell B contains **all** groups of the user you proof which is in cell A. 
may it helps someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a user is going to be member of multiple AD Groups. I don't know how exactly you intend to put that information in a CSV. But this should get you the information you need.

```
$ImportPath | ForEach-Object {get-aduser $_.sAMAccountName -properties MemberOf | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, GivenName, MemberOf} | Export-Csv 'c:\temp\groupmembership.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: the output of the groups is their DistinguishedName. I want only the names of the group (groups sAMAccountName). But Thanks at all